# XML Schema: Define default value in child complextype

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

We have a parent element which have an "implementationClass" attribute. This parent element have many children in which we would like to define a default value. Here is the definition of the parent element:

```
<xsd:complexType name="serviceType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:ID" />
        <xsd:element name="connection">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="reference" type="xsd:IDREF" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="implementationClass" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

To create a child element, with additionnal attribute, we need to use "extension". To define a default value, we need to use "restriction". However, these 2 are mutually exclusive.

Anybody can help me figure out how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effects of both "extension" and "restriction"
via some intermediate type:

```
serviceType -> serviceTypeIntermediate -> serviceTypeResult
```

For example:

```
<xsd:complexType name="serviceTypeIntermediate">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="serviceType">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="something" type="xsd:String"/>
      <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="serviceTypeResult">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="serviceTypeIntermediate">
      ...
    <xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

But please note the following:

**Extension** (of complex content) works so that new child elements (declared in it)
are added to the initial content as sequence.
That is, you cannot 'extend' those children already declared in the base type.

In **restriction**, you must define the entire content model anew.
But that new content must be fully compatible with the one defined in the base type.